# Present modal controller from specified point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have buttons on some viewController view. `touchUpInside:` methods present modal view controllers. I want to present them from center of tapped button frame. How can I achieve this result?
I tried:

```
webController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, self.buuton.center.x, self.button.center.y);
        [self presentViewController:webController animated:NO completion:^{
            // some code
        }];
```

but it damaged my UI. I also tried to use `[UIView beginAnimation]`, no success.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved something similar with a trick, adding destvc.view as subview to sourcevc.view, see below my functions to scale in and scale out.

You can use the same trick only as visual effect, and present your vc at the end, without animation:

```
    +(void) animWithAlpha:(float)alpha view:(UIView*)view{
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.15
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = alpha;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin) {}];
    }


    +(void) zoomIN:(UIViewController*)sourceViewController destination:(UIViewController*)destinationViewController fromPoint:(CGPoint)point{

        [sourceViewController.view addSubview:destinationViewController.view];
        [destinationViewController.view setFrame:sourceViewController.view.window.frame];
        [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.15, 0.1)];
        destinationViewController.view.center  = point;
        sourceViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        destinationViewController.view.alpha = 0.5;
        [self animWithAlpha:1 view:destinationViewController.view];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{
                             [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
                             destinationViewController.view.center  = sourceViewController.view.center;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if(finished){
                                 [destinationViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)];
                                 destinationViewController.view.center  = sourceViewController.view.center;
                                 sourceViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                             }
                         }];

    }

    +(void) zoomOUT:(UIViewController*)sourceViewController  destination:(UIView*)destination toPoint:(CGPoint)point{
        [sourceViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];
        [sourceViewController.parentViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [destination setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             [sourceViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)];
                             [sourceViewController.view setAlpha:1.0];
                             sourceViewController.view.center  = point;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if(finished){
                                 [sourceViewController.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];
                                 [sourceViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                                 sourceViewController.view.center  = point;
                                 [destination setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                             }
    }
```

Comment: What is `animWithAlpha:view:`? And how can you use self in `+` class method?

Comment: sorry I missed that, it works because animwithalpha is a class method as well. I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that through `addSubview:` method and doing something like:

```
- (void) appear: (UIView *) view fromPoint: (CGPoint) point
{
    [view setBounds:self.view.bounds];
    [view setCenter:point];
    [view setAlpha:0.0];
    [self addSubview:view];
    [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0)];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [view setCenter:self.view.center];
        [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
        [view setAlpha:1.0];
    }];
}
```

You have to create the view before call the method.

Good Luck!